# react native project does not allow touch in order to invoke either IBAction/WKWebkit/uiviewcontroller touch event present in native iOS project

Tags: swift, react-native, wkwebview

I have WKWebkit in iOS swift project which is displayed on screen using react reactive. Issue is I cannot get touch gesture on my WKWebkit while using react native.
If I use only the native iOS project just to cross check WKWebkit, it is working fine.

Why touch is not working if I use it through react native?

Expecting user touch to work using react native which in turn invokes WKWebkit present in native iOS code.